# Prompting user for integer 2> and >9 in C

Tags: c, parameters, integer, prompt

Really rookie question about C...

I want the user to enter a number between 2 and 9, and if they don't, the prompt repeats itself until an integer within my parameters is entered. I can get this to work with one parameter ie

```
  int between_2_and_8(string prompt)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("%s", prompt);
    }
    while (n > 8);
    return n;
}
```

but not having luck putting 2 parameters in. Here is the snippet:

```
int between_2_and_8(string prompt)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("%s", prompt);
    }
    while (n > 8);
    return n;

    while (n < 2);
    return n;

}
```

Comment: Try `while (n > 8);` --> `while (n > 8 || n < 2);`

Comment: while (n > 8 && n < 2). Basic C grammar.

Comment: @GenoChen `(n > 8 && n < 2)` is never true.

Comment: @chux Oh yes, my failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two conditions to continue your **do-while** loop .

Modify your code as below:

```
int between_2_and_8(string prompt)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("%s", prompt);
    }
    while (n < 3  || n > 8); // continue looping till either n is less than 3 or greater than 8
    return n;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Corrected conditions

Comment: The opposite of a number _larger than_ 2 and _smaller than_ nine is: `n<=2 || n>=9`. Alternatively `n<3 || n>8`. Or if it was meant to include 2 and 9, then `n<2 || n>9`.

Answer (score -1):

You will never enter the condition check `while(n < 2)` as either of the previous condition check or `return n` executes. ie. it loops around `while (n > 8)`when the condition is true or `return n`gets executed when the condition fails. So it will never execute the second condition check `while (n < 2)`.

Try implementing a logical OR in a single while loop as below

```
int between_2_and_8(string prompt)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("%s", prompt);
    }
    while (n < 3 || n > 8);// Loops around until n is either less than 2 or greater than 8
    return n;

}
```

**Edit** : Corrections made on condition check

Comment: The opposite of a number _larger than_ 2 and _smaller than_ nine is: `n<=2 || n>=9`. Alternatively `n<3 || n>8`. Or if it was meant to include 2 and 9, then `n<2 || n>9`.